# How can I make a sliding mechanism in this plywood side headrest that locks it into place?

Tags: plywood

[**Here's a clip**](https://imgur.com/a/Su30Bz4)

I'm building a wooden side headrest based on this idea: [image: image: headrest with side support]

I'm constantly adjusting the side (plywood) support based on my leaning position.

How do I make the adjustment easier like this:

- unlock > slide/adjust > lock

instead of:

- remove 2 clamps --> slide/adjust --> put back clamps.

Are there components I can buy that can achieve the sliding mechanism?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackExchange. Are you familiar with T-track and similar aluminium extrusion profiles that allow for various fixings to slide along the track and be locked in place?